# Not using auto_now=True with djangoforms makes GAE crash?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

This is my first night playing around with Google App Engine with djangoforms rather than straight Django. I don't understand why this happens with db.DateTimeProperty().

import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db

```
class BoringOldEvent(db.Model):
    """Models an individual Event that someone creates"""
    creator = db.StringProperty()
    date_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date_time = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

Will crash if `start_date_time = db.DateTimeProperty()` **does not** have `auto_now_add=True`.

I'm sure there is a good reason, but I"m left scratching my head at the moment because surely users expect to enter datetimes at some point....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/Users/mw/Documents/yayimin/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import events.views
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/Users/mw/Documents/yayimin/events/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    class EventForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 772, in __new__
    form_field = prop.get_form_field()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 353, in get_form_field
    return super(DateTimeProperty, self).get_form_field(**defaults)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 200, in get_form_field
    return form_class(**defaults)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/forms/fields.py", line 394, in __init__
    super(DateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/forms/fields.py", line 99, in __init__
    widget = widget()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/forms/widgets.py", line 414, in __init__
    self.format = formats.get_format('DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/utils/formats.py", line 67, in get_format
    if use_l10n or (use_l10n is None and settings.USE_L10N):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
INFO     2012-08-19 05:07:06,936 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Super duper thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, I wish I could tag this "lol noob" but I'm not sure that would be good SO policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you're using Python 2.5 or 2.7. If you're using 2.7, you need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable in your `app.yaml`:

```
env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myapp.settings'
```

See the [Django notes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#django).

Comment: Do you happen to know why it is fine and I don't need to define  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as long as I use auto_now_add=True? Thanks in advance for all of your help! Just trying to understand why the difference in args makes it panic and need the  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what auto_now_add does in Django. I'm hardly a Django expert. Did you get this working?